# How to pass predefined variable inside a normal variable for powershell task arguments using azure devops

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

Hi I have powershell script in azure devops. I used powershell task with file location. I used arguments to pass values. In that one variable name should be "**stage-wb2018**"
Powershell Script:

```
param (

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string] $API_TOKEN,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string] $url,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string] $TAG_VALUE_ENVIRONMENT

)



Write-Host "TAGVALUE is :$TAG_VALUE_ENVIRONMENT"

#$startTime = Get-Date -UFormat %s
$startTime = [double](Get-Date -Date ((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()) -UFormat %s) * 1000
$startTimeFormatted = Get-Date -UFormat "%x %R"

Write-Host "==============================================================="
Write-Host "Start Time: "$startTime
Write-Host "Start Time Formatted: "$startTimeFormatted
Write-Host "==============================================================="

#Write-Host ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=startTimeFormatted]$startTimeFormatted")
#Write-Host ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=startTime]$startTime")

#$test = stage_$(Environment.ResourceName)


Write-Host "$url"

# read Dynatrace values from the pipeline variables

$DYNATRACE_API_URL="$url" + "/api/v1/events"

# set the data for the API call
# adjust the number of tags in the JSON below and tag variables values

Write-Host "ENV Value: $TAG_VALUE_ENVIRONMENT"
Write-Host "Token Value: $API_TOKEN"
Write-Host "API URL: $DYNATRACE_API_URL"
```

powershell argument
-url $(URL) -API_TOKEN $(TOKEN) -TAG_VALUE_ENVIRONMENT '$(stage-$(Environment.ResourceName))'

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
  filePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/dynatrace.ps1'
  arguments: '-url $(URL) -API_TOKEN $(TOKEN) -TAG_VALUE_ENVIRONMENT ''$(stage-$(Environment.ResourceName))'''
```

Here we used Yaml pipeline with variables.
We have added variables and values like

1. stage-wb2018 = xxxxxxxxxxxx
2. stage-wb2019 = yyyyyyyyyyyy

we need to input xxxxxxxxxxx from pipeline to powershell script
wb2018, wb2019 are vm resource names. for that we are using (environment.resourcename).

This value dynamically have to take. But it is not taking. It only giving like $(stage-wb2018). Not replacing the variable value of stage-wb2018.

I am getting this output

- ENV Value: $(stage-raja-win)
- Token Value:123456789 API URL:
- https://testapp.com/api/v1/events

***But required output is***

- **ENV Value: xxxxxxxxxxxx #(stage-wb2018 value)**
- **Token Value: 123456789**
- **API URL: https://testapp.com/api/v1/events**

So please help us to solve this problem

Comment: `$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($TAG_VALUE_ENVIRONMENT)`?

Comment: Hi iRon I didn't understood. How to give variable inside a variable?